# How to write a onclick function inside a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, onclick

I'm using `React` and `<FormattedMessage` from `react-intl`

I have a json file

```
"a": "value is {value}",
"b":  "website is <a href=\"http://www.website.ac.io\" target=\"_blank\">www.website.con</a>"
```

I need to write an `onClick` function inside the value for `b`

```
"b":"website is <a onclick="{someFunction()}" href=\"http://www.website.ac.io\" target=\"_blank\">www.website.con</a>"

someFunction(){
    console.log("Showing Here");
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting

```
someFunctionis not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

How to write an onclick funtion inside json and read it on JSX

Comment: You can't define functions in JSON, and you really shouldn't define html tags in your json either. The real question would be why do you want to do this?

Comment: The exact reason is I need to capture, If `a href` is clicked

Comment: So why not use event handlers in javascript?

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu React, not a javascript. I'm using i18n (https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-react) of react

Comment: what do you think react is?

Comment: React is just a javascript framework. Anything you can do in Javascript, you can do in React